# Htaccess: force https for all and www for all except one folder

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use HTTPS and WWW for all requests and this code works fine for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But now I want to exclude one folder from www redirect (so all requests is redirected to www except one folder). I have tried to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foldername` above the last RewriteRule but without any luck. Any suggestions?

p.s. Apache/2.4.41 on CentOS.

Comment: Sounds right, though you would need to use a logical "AND" operator for the two conditions. Take a look into the documentation of the tool you are using to see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`.